# 3 Jframes in 1 larger Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm absolutely stuck on how to code this, could anybody please help me out? Basically I want 1 large JFrame, but inside it there will be three JFrames that have individual information Example- the CCC Jframe  receives the call for help from the customer, 
logs the call as a job, and if the problem can not be resolved immediately, leaves the 
problem in the system as a job to be handled by a TSO., then TSO Jframe will handles the jobs in the CSS, in the order they come.

Really stuck, help would be appreciated! Much Love~

I have this done -

```
  import java.awt.*;  
  import javax.swing.*;  

 public class Testing  
 {  
 public Testing()  
 {  
 JFrame window1 = new JFrame("Window 1");  
 JFrame window2 = new JFrame("Window 2");  

 //Container container = window1.getContentPane();  
 //container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());  
 JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Test in 1");  
 JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Test in 2");  
 window1.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());  
 window1.getContentPane().add(label1);  
 window2.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());  
 window2.getContentPane().add(label2);  
 window1.setSize(200, 100);  
  window1.setVisible(true);  

 window2.setSize(200, 100);  
 window2.setVisible(true);  

  }  

  public static void main(String [] args)  
  {  
 Testing app = new Testing();  
  }  
}
```

Just need help on adding the contents part and how to get them to be in 1 large Jframe I guess? Or for them not to be ontop of another.

Comment: Why do you need them each to be JFrames? Why can't you make them panels or some other component?

Comment: Take a look at [How to use internal frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html), but please note, the MDI paradigm has basically being deprecated since Windows 3.1.  A compound split pane design might be more suitable

Comment: @JNYRanger Thats what I've tried so far. Im sorry guys, very new to coding still.

Comment: @TheDavidTurner Since this is a GUI question, I think providing us with a quick mockup of what you want would be useful. I suspect you're mixing up your terms and mean panels when you say frames.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare I think I am mixing up my terms. Essentially,I want to have three windows open at all times. First window will be used for logging jobs and either resolving that job or passing it to the second window. Second window will be where those passed jobs will be put in order (first job sent from first windown, will be 1st job in 2nd window). Whilst the last window will list all pending jobs, saving data into a memory disk and able to forward jobs to 1&2 window

Comment: Text descriptions only go so far.  Provide ASCII art (or an image with a simple drawing) of the GUI as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Im currently visiting family in the hospital, will give do as you said when I get back home. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can create three panels to represent the each window as it is nice to see.
How ever you can use three javax.swing.JInternalFrame to build your application

You can use NetBeans Visual designer (Swing GUI Forms) to create the required Swing components (Drag n Drop feature)